# How to initialise an array without knowing the size it should be

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to write a method which returns an array containing only the numbers from `input` that are greater than or equal to `n`.

So far I have the following:

```
public static int[] filter(int[] input, int n) {

    int counter = 0;
    int[] res = new int[input.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if(input[i] >= n) {
            res[counter++] = input[i];
        }
    }   
    return res;
}
```

I am aware that `int[] res = new int[input.length]` is incorrect because it initialises the array with the size of the input array, but I cannot get it to work otherwise.

As a result, for `int[] input = {4,3,2,5,1,6}` and `int n = 3` I get `4 3 5 6 0 0`.

I presume it has something to do with the counter and I tried `int[] res = new int[counter]`
but since `counter = 0` it has length 0.

My question: how can I initialise the array `res` when I don't know how large it will be?

Comment: use a `List` when you need not-fixed size container :) look about ArrayList. Without that you need at the end to create a new array (3rd one) with the size you need, then copy the too-long array into the 3rd one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Shorten:** use java 8 `Stream` API

```java
public static int[] filter(int[] input, int n) {
    return IntStream.of(input).filter(i -> i >= n).toArray();
}
```

2. **Easiest:** use a non-fixed size wrapper, like a `List`

```java
public static Integer[] filter(int[] input, int n) {
    List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int val : input) {
        if (val >= n) {
            res.add(val);
        }
    }
    return res.toArray(new Integer[0]);
}
```

3. **Arrays only:** copy the needed value into an array with the appropriate size

```java
public static int[] filter(int[] input, int n) {
    int counter = 0;
    int[] res = new int[input.length];
    for (int val : input) {
        if (val >= n) {
            res[counter++] = val;
        }
    }
    int[] result = new int[counter];
    System.arraycopy(res, 0, result, 0, counter);
    return result;
}
```

The `System.arraycopy` line can be replaced by

```
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    result[i] = res[i];
}
```

Comment: How would you do this without `List`? We are not allowed to use such classes in my programming course and so we have to get around things like that with loops.

Comment: @h4ckerlinguist Read my answer fully, the last proposition use arrays only

Comment: Is there a way to not use `System.arraycopy`?

Comment: @h4ckerlinguist yes, it can be replaced by another loop, look my edit

Answer (score 3):

Don’t create the array; let the JDK do it for you:

```
public static int[] filter(int[] input, int n) {
    return Arrays.stream(input)
        .filter(i -> i >= n)
        .toArray();
}
```

It’s a lot less code too.

Comment: That isn't a valid filter ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try ArrarList as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList; //
ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
```